# Does the Tether USDT ERC20 have refund function? Accidentally sent to Token Contract Address

Tags: usdt

I accidentally sent money instead of the wallet address to the smart contract address. USDT Thether ERC20. Can you tell me if I can get the funds back? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, your money cannot be refunded